# Plugin for chrome or IE to isolate cookie usage?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, cookies

(I'm not sure the best way to word this, and I haven't found anything yet)

Is there a setting, or a plugin to allow me to isolate cookies to the site that originated the calls.  I.e. when a script is called from a 3rd party site, that can include cookie information.  I.e. this is how sites like FB track your usage across everything.

What I'm looking for is a way that when I go to BobsDomain.com who happens to be making calls to Facebook.com, instead of having cookies stores like this:

- BobsDomain.com/Cookie1
- Facebook.com/Cookie1

it would be stored like this:

- BobsDomain.com/Cookie1
- BobsDomain.com/Facebook.com/Cookie1.

That way when I go to another site, I get a new cookie from facebook, and it has no idea who I am.  Of course It should also have the ability to allow the cookies to be taken from other sites in particular instances.  (a user's choice)

Any one know of an existing plugin like this? For Chrome, IE, or some other browser?

- Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Membership with FB Connect? You use a flag in your membership database to indicate that the user was validated by Facebook or Twitter etc. credential validation. The Chromium and Edge dev tools has listings of domain cookies from the top document and embedded content (iframe).... Do NOT use iframes to host the FB connect sign-in.

Comment: @RobParsons, No. I'm trying to achieve browser security. I'm looking for a solution for maintaining privacy between sites, while allowing memory for logins and session states.  The cookies could be from anywhere.  I only brought up FB as a reference.  This has nothing to do with FB APIs in specific.  It is generic to cookie management on the browser.

Comment: Hi Dan, Users can change their browsers treatment of cookies from settings or with extensions(Add block, Tracking protection). (Internet Options>Privacy tab). You can use the Networking tab of a browser dev tool to inspect the request and response headers for the cookie crumb values.

Comment: To set up IE to list any blocked content (ActiveX filtering, Tracking protection) to Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages"... Save your changes.... now when you inspect a page, the console tab will list any messages and warning for blocked content (blocking content also blocks cookies).... Note that Flash has 'cookies' also. See your Flash control panel for a listing of sites using your file system to store info on your computer.

Comment: I'm looking for a plugin to do this automatically, and not have to worry about every request they make on the internet.

Comment: You can use GPO to configure the browsers Privacy settings and block 3rd party cookies list. See the Privacy tab, of Internet Options. Under the 'Settings' sections there are two buttons for 'Sites' and Advanced.
A GPO reference can be Downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=25250